# Accessingn docker containers per hostname

Tags: docker

To reach my containers per hostname from my hostmachine (win10) i had to add a static route `route /P add 172.18.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.0.75.2`. I also had to add entries in the hosts file for name resolution. Is there a better way to do that ?

actually i start my containers like this `docker run -p 443:443 --net=mynet --ip=172.18.0.3 --hostname=frontend.foobar.com frontend`

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a container with `docker exec` can be done only with the container ID or container name:

> docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

from 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

So if you want to access the container:

```
docker exec -it frontend bash
```

Comment: The OP wnats to reach the container per hostname

Comment: The hostname is just the name of the machine, and Docker doesn't store this information because it's futile and not relevant in Docker scope, thus you cannot access the container with the hostname. It's not because the OP want to travel to Mars, that it is feasable or possible to do so.